# Prevent Duplicate Name or Re-entry of Name on showing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

EDIT: Is it possible to query this? I have 2 table.

```
tithing table
tithings.MarrID = FK to Marriage table
tithings.Tithing_ID PK

tithingspayment table
tithingspayment.TP_ID = PK
tithingspayment.Tithing_ID = FK to tithings table "Tithing_ID"
Paid_Amount 
Paid_Month_Year = Date

Marr_ID | Tithing_ID | TP_ID | Tithing_ID | Paid_Amount | Paid_Month_Year | TP_ID | Tithing_ID | Paid_Amount | Paid_Month_Year | 
  1     |     2      |   5   |     2      |     10.00   |    Jan-2014     |   3   |      2     |     10.00   |     Feb-2014    |
```

Sorry for the long codes; what I'm trying to ask is that I wanted not to show same name in my table:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","RMS");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 30; 

$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM tithings
INNER JOIN marriage ON tithings.Marr_ID = marriage.MarrID
INNER JOIN tithings_payment ON tithings_payment.Tithing_ID = tithings.Tithing_ID WHERE YEAR( STR_TO_DATE( Dateregistered,  '%Y' ) ) <= $year LIMIT $start_from, 30"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);






echo "<div class='datagrid'><table>
<thead><tr>
<th>Family Name</th>
<th>Jan</th>
<th>Feb</th>
<th>Mar</th>
<th>Apr</th>
<th>May</th>
<th>June</th>
<th>July</th>
<th>Aug</th>
<th>Sep</th>
<th>Oct</th>
<th>Nov</th>
<th>Dec</th>
<th>Operations</th>
</tr></thead>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

$id = $row['Tithing_ID'];
echo "<tbody><tr>";
$MonthRegistered = date("F", strtotime($row['Dateregistered']));
$YearRegistered = date("Y", strtotime($row['Dateregistered']));

$PaidMonthYear = $row['Paid_Month_Year'];
$PaidAmount = $row['Paid_Amount'];


$January = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($January == "$year-01")
{$January = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$January = 0;}

$February = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($February == "$year-02")
{$February = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$February = 0;}

$March = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($March == "$year-03")
{$March = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$March = 0;}

$April = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($April == "$year-04")
{$April = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$April = 0;}

$May = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($May == "$year-05")
{$May = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$May = 0;}

$June = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($June == "$year-06")
{$June = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$June = 0;}

$July = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($July == "$year-07")
{$July = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$July = 0;}

$August = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($August == "$year-08")
{$August = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$August = 0;}

$September = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($September == "$year-09")
{$September = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$September = 0;}

$October = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($October == "$year-10")
{$October = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$October = 0;}

$November = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($November == "$year-11")
{$November = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$November = 0;}

$December = date("Y-m", strtotime($row['Paid_Month_Year']));
if($December == "$year-12")
{$December = $row['Paid_Amount'];}
else{$December = 0;}

if ($YearRegistered <= $year)
{$FamilyHead = $row['FName_Groom']. ", " . $row['LName_Groom'];

$operation = "<td class=operations>" . "<a class='detail' href='../record_detail.php?id=$id'>Details</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp<a class='pay' href='payment.php?id=$id'>Pay</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp<a class='edit' href='../record_edit.php?id=$id'>Edit</a></td>";
}else{
$FamilyHead = "<style>
tbody{
display:none;
}
</style>";
$operation = "";
}


echo "<td>" . $FamilyHead ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $January . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $February . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $March ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $April . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $May . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $June . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $July ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $August . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $September . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $October ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $November . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $December . "</td>";
echo $operation;

  }
```

**Tithing(Table)**

```
Marr_ID(FK) | Tithing_ID (PK) | Dateregistered | Pledge | Barangay  | Address | 
      5     |        1        | Sept, 13 2014  | 15.00  | Barangay1 | Address |
      6     |        2        |  Jan, 13 2014  | 15.00  | Barangay1 | Address |
```

**Marriage (Table)**

```
MarrID (PK) | FName_Groom | LName_Groom | MName_Groom | 
 5          |    Name(5)  |   LName(5)  |   MName(5)  |
 6          |    Name(6)  |   LName(6)  |   MName(6)  |
```

**Tithing_payment(Table)**

```
Tithing_P_ID(PK) | Tithing_ID(FK) | Payment_Date_Received | Paid_Amount | Paid_Month_Year |
        1        |        1       |     Sept, 13 2014     |     15.00   |   Sept,01 2014  |
        2        |        1       |     Sept, 13 2014     |     15.00   |    Oct,01 2014  |
        3        |        2       |     Sept, 13 2014     |     15.00   |    Jan,01 2014  |
        4        |        2       |     Sept, 13 2014     |     15.00   |    Feb,01 2014  |
```

**My Query Statement is**

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM tithings
INNER JOIN marriage ON tithings.Marr_ID = marriage.MarrID
INNER JOIN tithings_payment ON tithings_payment.Tithing_ID = tithings.Tithing_ID WHERE YEAR( STR_TO_DATE( Dateregistered,  '%Y' ) ) <= $year LIMIT $start_from, 30";
```

The Paid_Month_Year = Month(Jan-Dec) I used PHP if else statement

And the result is this.

```
Family Name |   Jan   |   Feb   | Mar | Apr | May | June | July | Aug |   Sep   |   Oct   | Nov | Dec |
    Name(5) |    0    |    0    |  0  |  0  |  0  |   0  |   0  |  0  |  15.00  |    0    |  0  |  0  |
    Name(5) |    0    |    0    |  0  |  0  |  0  |   0  |   0  |  0  |    0    |  15.00  |  0  |  0  |
    Name(6) |  15.00  |    0    |  0  |  0  |  0  |   0  |   0  |  0  |    0    |    0    |  0  |  0  |
    Name(6) |    0    |  15.00  |  0  |  0  |  0  |   0  |   0  |  0  |    0    |    0    |  0  |  0  |
```

**Note:** I tried Distinct In query didn't work.

What I wanted my output to look like is this;

```
Family Name |   Jan   |   Feb   | Mar | Apr | May | June | July | Aug |   Sep   |   Oct   | Nov | Dec |
    Name(5) |    0    |    0    |  0  |  0  |  0  |   0  |   0  |  0  |  15.00  |  15.00  |  0  |  0  |
    Name(6) |  15.00  |  15.00  |  0  |  0  |  0  |   0  |   0  |  0  |    0    |    0    |  0  |  0  |
```

Comment: You can try `GROUP BY Family Name`?

Comment: Can you also provide data for `marriage` table ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I added it now I only put the data that's being used. bcoz my data structure composed of 31. But if you want I'll add it.

Comment: @S.Pols Hello, I did try that but it will return 1 row for each of them 
Like Name(5) only show that SEP have 15.00 and the Oct does not.
It will only show 1 Paid_Month_Year value.

Comment: if you group, you have to take the `SUM` over the monthts.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, you have to do something with the columns which you don't use in the group statement. In your case it makes sense to take the SUM, because someone could pay something twice in the same month, and also in another one.

```
SELECT
 Family_Name,
 SUM(Jan),
 SUM(Feb)
 ....
 SUM(Dec) 
FROM
 tithings
INNER JOIN marriage ON tithings.Marr_ID = marriage.MarrID
INNER JOIN tithings_payment ON tithings_payment.Tithing_ID = tithings.Tithing_ID
WHER
 YEAR( STR_TO_DATE( Dateregistered,  '%Y' ) ) <= $year
GROUP BY
 Family_Name
LIMIT $start_from, 30
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have table column for Jan-Dec
I determined them from Paid_Month_Year

Sorry my explanation is so confusing
the output on my table is php+mysql

Comment: but, is the date saved in your database a date or a string? if it's a date, you can also group by the month and year. and just take the sum of the amount. in php you can loop over the results for every family id and display the right ones.

Comment: its a date.
by the way is there anyway that I can duplicate the value of Paid_Month_Year? since I have two values but they don't share the same value. thank you. you can check my edited post